# Firebase Rules wildcard Key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've searched the forums for an answer to this but can't find one.
I'm writing a Key:value pair to firebase database and want to set rule.

It's a chat application, and I'm adding a field to my user for each chat he's a member of, eg user/$uid/chat/$chat_id

The chatId i'm creating using

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").push().getKey();
```

I'm trying to add some kind of validation so that the data has to contains $chat_id : true.
But I'm strugging to get the wildcard to work.

The test data I'm writing -
"-M5STgMVWyafV-LhPIT2": "true", but I need the Key to be a wildcard as it's random each time.

The data structure looks like this.

```
chat
    -M5STgMVWyafV-LhPIT2   // <<< $chat_id
        info
            admin: "zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE2"
            groupName: "Some Group"
            id: "-MJD6cAtpxY_jmFyk-sb"
            no_of_users: 2
            timer: 60000
            users
                y1EKihfmIJTDCD9OJt0N89WDC642: true
                zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE2: true
        messages
            -MJ0G0gdecak8ACR7fb2
                creator: "wjl8VNmcaPNHJAUQnCDRHWkJ33p2"
                date: "Oct 06, 2020"
                text: "Some Text"
                time: "23:13"
                userName: "Bob"

user
    zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE2
        chat
            -M5STgMVWyafV-LhPIT2: true  // <<< $chat_id
            -MGNk6fl8jneDhw7Jv02: true
            -MGNkFGD4OYb7ZSzX8P2: true
            -MGNl47kbPuNZFc3RLD2: true
            -MGNyFIuhjrwyQT4VME2: true
            -MGNydtnFHW60i5TbzW2: true
            -MJ-ETJ-LcOxvYkZ8b72: true

        info
            email: "someemailaddress@me.com"
            name: "Bob"
            notificationKey: "be5df5fa-3a20-4704-986f-8a35d"
            profilePic: "https://"
            status: "Some status"
    zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3
    zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE4
```

And the rules I've tried, which work if I specify the $chat_id as a string.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user": { 
      ".read": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": "info/email",
      "$user_id": {
          
                "chat": {                           
                ".write": "auth != null",
                ".validate": "newData.child($chat_id).val() == 'true'", // <<< this doesn't work Unknown variable '$chat_id'.
                //".validate": "newData.child("-M5STgMVWyafV-LhPIT2").val() == 'true'",  <<< this works, but not $chat_id, I need this Child to be a wildcard

              },
               "info": { 
                //".indexOn": "email", 
                ".write": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid",
              },
            }
        },
    "chat": {
     //".write": "auth != null && !data.child('chat').child('$chat_id').exists()",
    "$chat_id": {
          "info": {
            ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
            ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists()&&newData.child('admin').val()==auth.uid || data.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
          },
          "messages": {
              "$message_id": {
                ".write": "root.child('chat').child($chat_id).child('info').child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
                ".read": "root.child('chat').child($chat_id).child('info').child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()",    
             }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Any help would be apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I tried to help below, but am not sure if I understand the problem correctly. If this is not the problem, please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to contains the [minimal-but-complete rules, JSON and code that are needed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now you're showing fragments of each, which makes it much harder to help.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to keep the example to a bare minimum. You've grasped my issue tho, I need the key, the $chat_id, to be a wildcard, and the value to always be true. I'll try your suggestion a bit later and if that doesn't work, will update my question with more info. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks like you applied the change I indicated in my answer, which means the lookup of the user in the chat should now work. Can you edit the question to also show the code that is not working as you expect it?

Comment: Thanks Frank, I've added in the line that's erroring for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct syntax for this. I needed to add the variable after the write function, and then put the validate after the variable.

Here it is in case it helps anyone later.

```
      "$user_id": {
            "chat": {                           
                  ".write": "auth != null",
                "$chat_id":    {
                  ".validate": "$chat_id.length === 20 && newData.val() === 'member'",
                },
                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
newData.hasChild('$chat_id')
```

Means that you're checking if the new data has a child node that is literally called `$chat_id`. Aside from the fact that this can't be true (as `$` is not allowed in keys), it is also likely not what you want.

If you instead want to check if the new data has a child with the same value as `$chat_id` in your database, use `$chat_id` without quotes. So:

```
newData.hasChild($chat_id)
```

Comment: Hi Frank, I've tried this suggestion and I've got "Unknown variable '$chat_id'". So obviously I need to declare it somewhere, I'm just not sure where, I've updated my question with more full deatils of my databse and Rules. Thanks

Comment: And Perhaps a better question would be, if I'm writing to a chat node under a users node,  to list their membership. How do I secure that data, if I'm writing something like this "-M5STgMVWyafV-LhPIT2": "true"